# How to view Execution Plans for Oracle Database in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, statistics

With SQL Plus for Oracle Database, I can call

SET autotrace on

and then see Execution Plan, statistics, etc.

The problem is that I want access to information about the Execution Plan and statistics in my Java program.  I typically have done something like this to execute a sql statement,

Connection connection = //INITIALIZE HERE;

Statement getColumn = connection.createStatement();

ResultSet results = getColumn.executeQuery("INSERT SQL QUERY HERE");

while(results.next())
{
    //view results
}

Is there a way I can get the Execution Plan and Statistics?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the V$SQL_PLAN table to get the explain plain. Alternatively you can query the PLAN_TABLE, you can see more details on this [HERE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm).

Comment: or SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(:sql_id)). The trick is trying to work out the id of the statement you executed.